# Order mySQL results based of the current time and the chosen time by the user?

Tags: php, mysql

In my page I show some entries based on the range of the chosenTime a user chosen to get contacted, and saved it into mySQL.

I have 4 range groups of times (our working times 09:00-17:00) that a user can select from

```
09:00-11:00
11:00-13:00
13:00-15:00
15:00-17:00
```

For now, I show the results as below, order by the chosenTime

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table order by chosenTime asc";
```

What I want to do is to sort the results based on the current time.

For example if time is 10:30, show first the rows that the chosen time is between 09:00-11:00.
If it is 11:00, show first the 11:00 - 13:00 results.

I am thinking about a `between` but I don't know on how to proceed with this.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you afford to store the range as two integers e.g start at 9 finish at 11. Matching a string like '09:00-11:00' against the current hour is going to be painful.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson No, I can not do this. Maybe a regex will help to clear the values I guess

Comment: Not sure if that's what you want to do, but you can `ORDER BY` multiple fields, for example: `ORDER BY field1,field2`

Comment: Yuck. Better to build a string XX:00-YY:00 from (current hour - 9) div 2 * 2 + 9 and current hour - 9 div 2 * 2 + 11, then you can order by whether the value in the table = the current time range. Messy, very messy.

Answer (score 0):

The first method that would come to mind for me would be to make sub-tables where time is either between the values or not. Something like

```
Select *
    FROM 
        (Select *, 1 as priority FROM table where time between STARTTIME and ENDTIME) UNION 
        (Select *, 2 as priority FROM table where time NOT between STARTTIME and ENDTIME) 
ORDER BY priority
```

This should give you results with the results relevant to the current STARTTIME and ENDTIME of your working period first.

Comment: Thank you. Can you be more descriptive ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `chosenTime` is character type, in a fixed and canonical format, it's not at all difficult.

We need the current time in the format `hh:mm` (e.g. 10:30) to match the stored format.

If we want to get current time from the database in that format, that's a simple expression:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%h:%i')
```

The ugly part is going to be splitting the character string. Given a fixed format `hh:mm-hh:mm`, we can use simple SUBSTR functions:

```
SUBSTR(ct,1,5)  -- begin
SUBSTR(ct,7,5)  -- end
```

You could definitely use a BETWEEN comparator, but note that on the boundaries, when the current time is on the edge (e.g. 13:00), we'll get a "match" on both the `11:00-13:00` and the `13:00-15:00`  periods.

```
 ORDER
    BY DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%h:%i') BETWEEN SUBSTR(ct,1,5) AND SUBSTR(ct,7,5) DESC
     , ct
     , ...
```

Note that the first expression is evaluated as a boolean, and will return either a `1` (true), `0` (false), or `NULL` (unknown).  We add the `DESC` keyword so that the true conditions (returned as a value of 1) will be sorted before the false.

---

This isn't the normal pattern we use for dealing with time values, but this will work for chosenTime in a fixed and canonical format. (This works with the 24-hour clock, but woululdn't work with a 12-hour clock, or single digit hours, etc. That is, for this to work, we have to guarantee that a string comparison is equivalent to a time comparison.)